# Pattern that matches a string containing elements of a group of strings to use on preg_grep

Tags: php, regex, combinations

I've been breaking my head on this for weeks without being able to find or create the right answer:

Let's say I have an array containing the following elements:

```
',1,'
',2,'
',1,2,'
',1,3,'
',1,2,3,'
```

And by using PHP's function preg_grep, I want to get all possible combinations that contain elements 1 or/and 2 (inclusive or), but only 1 and 2, so basically the elements I would like to get in this case are:

```
',1,'
',2,'
',1,2,'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks !!

EDIT: As requested by anubhava, a dataset in which I would use this is as follows:

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13602,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13606,

,13599,13600,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13600,13601,13602,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13602,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13600,13601,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13600,13601,13602,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13600,13601,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13602,13603,13604,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,

,13598,13600,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13606,

,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13601,13602,13603,13604,13605,

,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13606,

,13599,13601,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13604,13605,13606,

,13599,13601,13602,13604,13605,13606,

,13600,13602,13603,13604,13605,13606,

,13598,13599,13600,13602,13604,13605,

,13598,13599,13600,13602,13604,13606,

,13598,13600,13602,13603,13604,13606,

,13598,13601,13603,13604,13605,13606,

And for example i'm looking for all "childs" as I call them of:

,13598,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13606,

So basically everyone of that list that contains one, or more of this numbers:

13598,13599,13600,13601,13602,13603,13604,13606

And only those numbers.

Comment: You could just loop over the array and use string functions to check for the presence of `,1,` or/and `,2,`.

Comment: Problem is that the array in this case is of about 5 million entries, what I wrote was just a simple example and the double loop does not only consume about 3gb of memory but also takes an hour..

Comment: In a single array? You might want to do this in the database instead (if that's where the information comes from...).

Comment: If I can get this to work, then I can also use the same regular expression on an aggregation query on the db table :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_grep`:

```
/^,((?:13598|13599|13600|13601|13602|13603|13604|13606),)+$/
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xJ2iO1)

Comment: That would only work with numbers 0 to 9, if I reach 10 it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Explain your problem clearly by editing your question and adding a sample data for which this regex doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks !! you're awesome ! Would Upvote, but this thing doesn't let me due to reputation :(

Comment: You're most welcome, glad it worked. Accepting the answer is good enough :)